# Multirow and multicolumn tabular for (one and a) half line

Tags: multicolumn, multirow

I know that it is not good typographical practice to add all these vertical lines to a table head. But I would like to create a substitute for and existing document and this contains these lines. I managed to create the tabular head except on vertical line:

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}

%+----+------+--------------------------+---------------+
%|    |      |         Generated by     | Generated and |
%| No | Code +--------+-------+---------+ described on  |
%|    |      | Master | Slave | Gateway |   Layer       |
%+----+------+--------+-------+---------+---------------+

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{No} & 
        \multirow{3}{2.4cm}{Code} &
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Generated by }} &
        \multirow{3}{2.5cm}{Generated and described on Layer} 
        \\
        & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} &  \\ \cline{3-5}
        & & Master & Slave & Gateway & \\
        \hline\hline
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The ASCII art in the LaTeX source shows the idea of desired result. But the vertical line between column 5 and column 6 is not complete.

How can I draw this line?

Another point is that the multi-column over column 3-5 uses only one line for Master/Slave/Gateway. The separator (`\cline`) above should be a half line higher. This would require something like a multi-row for 1.5 lines. How can this be implemented with LaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `\multicolumn{3}{l}{}` overwrites the vertical lines resulting in the small gap you see. Add the line back in using `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{No} & 
        \multirow{3}{2.4cm}{Code} &
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Generated by }} &
        \multirow{3}{2.5cm}{Generated and described on Layer} 
        \\
        & & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} &  \\ \cline{3-5}
        & & Master & Slave & Gateway & \\
        \hline\hline
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Update regarding the second part of the question: In the following example, I have used a nested tabular for the "Generated by" part of the header. With this approach, I got rid of all `\multirow` commands. In order to make sure, teh last column's header takes up three rows, I used `\makecell` from the `makecell` package, but you could also use a fixed width column type here. In order to make sure, the line below "Generated by" ends up higher, I used the `cellspace` package, the neccessary amount of the top and bottom limit were detemined via trial and error. Lastly, I used `wc` type columns from the `array` package in combination with `\widthof` from the `calc` package to make sure columns 3 to 5 have the same width as their corresponding headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|wc{\widthof{Master}}|wc{\widthof{Slave}}|wc{\widthof{Gateway}}|c|}
        \hline
        No & 
        Code &
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}|}{\begin{tabular}{0c|0c|0c} \multicolumn{3}{0c}{Generated by} \\ \hline Master & Slave & Gateway \end{tabular} } &
        \makecell[cl]{Generated and\\ described on\\ Layer} \\
        \hline\hline
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great finding! But this overwriting effect would imply that the tabular "cells" are opaque. Did expected that because it doesn't overwrite the text "Generated by". Probably the `\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}` creates only space glyphs that are not tall enough to overlap with the text "Generated by".

Comment: Any idea above rising the `\cline` output to get the one-and-half split in the columns 3-5?

Comment: @harper: Regarding the cline: I have edited my answer to also include a suggestion on that part of the table.

Comment: Thanks, his fits perfect. And I realize that there is so much to learn with LaTeX.

Comment: I think it would be better to put `\multicolumn{3}{c|}` instead of `\multicolumn{3}{|c|}`. The output is the same but it would not be the same when using `array` (which I should recommend here).